# jQuery Debounce Resize

Tags: jquery, events, window

[In this example here](http://play.meyouand.us/130219-windowloadresize/test1.html), I'm trying to get the H1 tag to behave like a clickable button when it's in mobile mode. When it returns to the desktop mode, I need to make sure that the button is no longer clickable.

The button works properly when the page is initially loaded in "mobile-mode" to make sure that in mobile mode, the button only fires every single click. However, after resizing, it 1. doesn't unbind the clicking, and 2. it seems to fire off multiple times again.

I'm sure I'm doing this out of order or inefficiently. Any other better ways of doing this is welcomed!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.mobile-mode { background: pink; }
.mobile-mode h1 { background: yellow; padding: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; cursor: poi
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_jquery/jquery.debouncedresize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_jquery/jquery.throttledsize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("debounced", function() {
        var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
        $('.v-width span').html(viewportWidth);
        if ( viewportWidth < 640 ) {
                $('.device span').html('mobile');
                $('body').addClass('mobile-mode');
                $('h1').click(function() {
                        $('.results').append('<li>Hey!</li>');
                });
        } else {
                $('.device span').html('desktop');
                $('body').removeClass('mobile-mode');
                $('h1').unbind();
        }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="v-width">viewport width: <span></span></div>

<div class="device">device: <span></span></div>

<h1>Contextual Header Button</h1>

<ol class="results"></ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot: I called the function incorrectly as "debounced", when I should have called it "debouncedresize".